# Servlet returning response unexpectedly in Base64 format

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, servlets, solr

This is about a weird behaviour that I have witnessed while making a `servlet` that calls and fetches data from `Apache Solr` based on some parameters that I supply to `servlet`.

The `servlet` queries `Solr` and returns data to me in json format. Then verify it by placing a `System.out.println(response)`. It was in json format only.

My issue is that when I received same response over a client who was consuming this service, data returned in `Base64` format. In my code, I wrote not even a single line that converts the response into `Base64`. The only line I wrote before sending response were `resp.setContentType("application/json")`.

Though I later solved it by setting `resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`in my `servlet` before sending response. Then I received only `JSON` response every time I queried on client side or over a `REST client`. But still I am wondering, why that happened, why a response that was sent as a `JSON` from `servlet` converts into `Base64`?

Has anyone experienced something like this before?

I am using Apache Tomcat as my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely the property of your Java servlet framework. It is possible that your Solr content includes characters from Unicode range outside of English. So, the algorithm thinks it is actually a binary response and encodes it into base64 (possibly with a changed mime-type header).

Setting character encoding tells the framework that the full range of characters is expected and no escaping is required.

Or this could be in Tomcat. But the focus in your documentation search should be on escaping binary content, in my opinion.

Comment: In my servlet when I print the response received from Solr , it is all JSON only . And the whole index in Solr consists of English language only .So, are you trying to say that Tomcat interpreted that the response deserved to be sent in Base64 ? One point to note here is that while I make an HTTP POST request to Solr inside my servlet I already set my encoding as UTF-8 . So why I still need to set response enforcing character encoding as UTF-8 ? Also , the same servlet when run inside Google App Engine do not create such issues , and response is received in JSON format only .

Comment: Well, you are answering your own questions. What difference triggers the encoding? Sounds like Tomcat, so focus on that.

Comment: Hmm...will do that . But since that issue is resolved by setting the character encoding , only afterthoughts can  be made.Tried Tomcat documentation for this kind of behaviour, didn't find any specific statements .But it does raises a question that integrity of data format is so vulnerable that an Application Server can alter it based on its consideration ?